# Xamarin.Forms XAML Workbook Demonstration (Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How Can i do this for the Android Xamarin Workbook ?

I'm stack at

```
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    var a = new App();
    KeyWindow.RootViewController = a.MainPage.CreateViewController();
```

How to this for Android :

1. Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(**needs 2 pram**)
2. KeyWindow.RootViewController
3. a.MainPage.CreateViewController()

---

Here Is the Code For iOS

https://developer.xamarin.com/workbooks/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml/LoadXaml.workbook

## Xamarin.Forms XAML Workbook Demonstration (iOS)

### Steps to use XAML

*1.* Start by importing the NuGets for Xamarin.Forms and the iOS Platform Renderers

```csharp

```
    #r "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS"
    #r "Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    #r "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml"
    #r "Xamarin.Forms.Platform"
```

```

And for this hack to work, add the [Dynamic Xamarin Forms (preview)](http://www.cazzulino.com/dynamic-forms.html)
NuGet (which contains the magic to load XAML from a string):

```csharp

```
    #r "Xamarin.Forms.Dynamic"
```

```

*2.* Add the `using` statements next:

```csharp

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
```

```

*3.* Write up a simple XAML `ContentPage`to render on iOS:

```csharp

```
    static string xaml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns='http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms'
        xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
        x:Class='XamlPage'
        Title='Xaml Text' Padding='40'>
        <StackLayout Orientation='Vertical'>
            <Label Text='Hello from XAML' x:Name='helloLabel'/>
            <BoxView Color='Blue' WidthRequest='300' HeightRequest='2' />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>";
```

```

*4.* Bootstrap the Xamarin.Forms app object and and for the main page class, then use the **Dynamic Xamarin Forms** `LoadFromXaml` extension method to parse the `xaml` string:

```csharp

```
    public class App : Application
    {
        public ContentPage XamlPage {get;set;}
        public App ()
        {
            XamlPage = new ContentPage();
            XamlPage.LoadFromXaml (xaml); // loads XAML

            MainPage = XamlPage;
        }
    }
```

```

*5.* Finally, set the iOS root view controller directly (in a real Xamarin.Forms app, this would be taken care of by the `FormsApplicationDelegate` subclass):

```csharp

```
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    var a = new App();
    KeyWindow.RootViewController = a.MainPage.CreateViewController();
```

```

### One More Thing...

Loading XAML in this way does not allow strongly-typed access to the elements by their `x:Name`, instead they can only be referenced using `FindByName`as shown here to update the label:

```csharp

```
    var l = a.XamlPage.FindByName<Xamarin.Forms.Label>("helloLabel");
    l.Text = "Updated by the Workbook!";
    a.XamlPage.Content
```

```

Comment: Are you asking that how to use a page in PCL as a new `Activity` in Android client?

Comment: inside the workbook https://developer.xamarin.com/workbooks/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml/LoadXaml.workbook this is for ios i want this for Android